# Кастомная прошивка для точки доступа

Tags: маршрутизатор, прошивка, tp-link

Имеется точка доступа [TP-LINK TL-WA901ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WA901ND). Интересует вопрос: существует ли возможность прошить на нее какую-либо кастомную прошивку и расширить ее функционал до роутера? Если у кого-нибудь положительный опыт в кастомных прошивках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openwrt если имеются глубокие знания Linux http://openwrt.org

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел для второй версии [инструкцию](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd), однако, насколько я понял, там требуется специальный адаптер для подключения его к COM-порту для перепрошивки. А с паяльником я, к сожалению, на "вы".

Comment: не совсем так шьется через web, а если брик то только rs232

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало. Отличная прошивка, умеет практически все, даже менеджер пакетов есть.Веб-интерфейс, кстати, тоже имеется.

Comment: Рад был помочь. Функций действительно много.

Answer (score 1):

Да, имеется.

[Прошивка от DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно понял, что он прошивается штатными средствами через веб-интерфейс? Или нужны какие-либо дополнительные манипуляции?

Comment: Все стандартными средствами.

Comment: Увы, там прошивка только для первой версии точки доступа. А у меня, как на зло, именно вторая.А вторая версия, судя по форуму, уже 1.5 года как "work in progress".